# Send Post Data or Get Data on socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to send a POST or GET data in socket.io but I can't receive any data. I want to send the data outside the connection. Below is my code:

**Server code: app.js**

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('You Have successfully Connected to the server');
});

io.sockets.on('checkUser', function (data) {
    io.sockets.emit('callback', {
        data: data
    });
});
```

**Client Side: app.js**

```
$('.key').click(function () {
    var splitItem = $(this).find('.inputKey').val().split('-');;
    var info = {
        userid: user_id,
        itemid: splitItem[0], // keyid
        box: splitItem[1], // boxid
        username: username,
    }
    socket.emit('checkUser', {
        data: info 
    });
});

socket.on('callback', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by outside the connection?
did you call listen() on the server? and connect() on the client as shown at http://socket.io/ ?

Comment: i just want to send a POST or a GET..so that i can run my MYSQL QUERY

Answer (score 3):

if you just want to send a simple http call think again if you have to use socket.io, socket.io built mainly for sending data between client and server in realtime.

to use node.js for querying your mysql database and much more check out http://expressjs.com/  web application framework